# Create Spring 3 annotation that check Session for object and redirect the user

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm used to implement custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite` for my projects, but now in some methods I have the repetitive code block

```
...
if (param != null){
    return SiteMap.withRedirect(HOME); // resolves to "redirect:/home"
}
...
```

Is there a lean way to do this block outside from the controller methods?

Thanks in advance.

Answer to that:

`HandlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(Class<T>)` will help a lot :D

https://gist.github.com/dgomesbr/5657473

```
public class UserRequiredAnnotationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
{
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception
    {
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (((HandlerMethod) handler).getMethodAnnotation(RequiredUser.class) != null)
        {
            final Object userkey = request.getSession().getAttribute(LoginFilter.CURRENT_LOGGED_USER_ATTRIBUTE);
            if (userkey == null)
            {
                response.sendRedirect(SiteMap.HOME_REDIRECT);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement an [interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) with a `preHandle()` method.

> The preHandle(..) method returns a boolean value. You can use this
>   method to break or continue the processing of the execution chain.
>   When this method returns true, the handler execution chain will
>   continue; when it returns false, the DispatcherServlet assumes the
>   interceptor itself has taken care of requests (and, for example,
>   rendered an appropriate view) and does not continue executing the
>   other interceptors and the actual handler in the execution chain.

However, since `preHandle()` doesn't return a `String` like your controller method does the interceptor implementation would be along the lines of

```
if (request.getParameter(yourParam) == true) {
  return true;
} else (
  response.sendRedirect(redirectPath);
  return false;
}
```

Alternatively, you can of course put nearly the same code into a Servlet filter. The main difference is that the interceptor configuration in your MVC .xml files gives you more fine grained control over the "URL patterns" (i.e. your controller methods) the interceptor should be mapped to.

Comment: On the interceptor, the actual handler is an instance of HandlerMethod, so it's possible to inspect its arguments and look for annotations?

Thanks for the insight though.

Comment: I'll wait for a few more hours before granting you the bounty, but again, thanks for pointing me out on the right direction

Comment: In general annotation information can only ever be read reflectively if their [retention policy](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) is `RUNTIME`. Hence, it depends on the particular annotation anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A spring interceptor would be the way to go.